# jQuery初心者です。

Tags: jquery

jQueryに関して質問させてください。
下記Gナビをスクロールすると、ヘッダーの上部に固定するプログラミングをしています。

```
<nav class="g-nav">
 <div class="nav-innner">
  <ul class="g-nav-menu">
   <li>HOME</li>
   <li>概要</li>
   <li>特長</li>
   <li>例</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

【jQuery】

```
$(function() {
var gNav = $(".g-nav");
var gNavOffset = gNav.offset();

$(window).scroll(function () {
if($(this).scrollTop() > gNavOffset.top && gNav.hasClass('fixed') == false) {
gNav.css({"top": '-70px'});
gNav.addClass('fixed');
gNav.animate({"top": 0},500);
}
else if($(this).scrollTop() < gNavOffset.top && gNav.hasClass('fixed') == true){
gNav.removeClass('fixed');
}
});
});
```

jQueryの2行目の.g-navとなっている箇所を、.g-nav li　のような形で設定する方法はないでしょうか。

.gnavのliのデザインをcssを付与することで変更したいです。

また、.fixedというcssを追加して固定する仕組みなのですが、こちら、例えば.fixed001というcssも同時に追加するにはどのように記述すればよろしいのでしょう。

ご存知の方、ご教授くだされば幸いです。

Comment: JavaScriptで制御するのではなく、CSSの`position: fixed`を使うのはダメですか？

Comment: タイトルには、自己紹介ではなく、質問の内容を簡潔に記述して下さい。

Comment: マルチポスト　http://dixq.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=19208

Answer (score 2):

.g-nav li　のような形で指定は　’>’（子セレクタの指定）を使い

```
$(".g-nav-menu>li").css({"display":"inline-block"});
```

のように指定します。
クラスの複数設定は(.fixedと.fixed001の追加)

```
$(".g-nav-menu>li").addClass("fixed").addClass("fixed001");
または、$(".g-nav-menu>li").addClass("fixed fixed001");
```

です。
参考までに、position: fixedを使わない、（jQueryを使って、）ヘッダーを上部に固定する一番単純な方法は、クラス g-nav 付いているブロックへ　position:relativeを設定し　クラス g-nav 付いているブロックのtopへ windowスクロール移動値を設定すればよいです。（実際動作は、上下にガタガタしますが。）

```js
$(function() {
$(".g-nav-menu>li").css({"display":"inline-block"});
var gNav = $(".g-nav");
//var gNavOffset = gNav.offset();

$(window).scroll(function () {
  gNav.css({"top": $(this).scrollTop()});
//if($(this).scrollTop() > gNavOffset.top && gNav.hasClass('fixed') == false) {
//gNav.css({"top": '-70px'});
//gNav.addClass('fixed');
//gNav.animate({"top": 0},500);
//}
//else if($(this).scrollTop() < gNavOffset.top && //gNav.hasClass('fixed') == true){
//gNav.removeClass('fixed');
//}
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<nav class="g-nav" style="position: relative">
    <div class="nav-innner">
        <ul class="g-nav-menu">
            <li>HOME</li>
            <li>概要</li>
            <li>特長</li>
            <li>例</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div style="height: 3000px;">
1<br />
2<br />
3<br />
4<br />
5<br />
6<br />
7<br />
8<br />
9<br />
10<br />
1<br />
2<br />
3<br />
4<br />
5<br />
6<br />
7<br />
8<br />
9<br />
10<br />
1<br />
2<br />
3<br />
4<br />
5<br />
6<br />
7<br />
8<br />
9<br />
10<br />
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: yyzさん

丁寧なご回答を本当にありがとうございました。おかげさまで実装することが出来ました。